# Correct way to configure security for cross-database function invocation

Tags: sql-server

For security reasons our data is separated into a number of different databases.
I'm having trouble configuring the security such that restricted logins can access specific data from another database via a function invocation.

I've created a simple scenario which demonstrates the problem below: (run as sa or some other admin user)

```
CREATE DATABASE Test1
GO
USE Test1
CREATE Login TestA WITH PASSWORD='changeme'
CREATE USER TestA FOR LOGIN TestA
GO
CREATE DATABASE Test2
GO
USE Test2
CREATE Login TestB WITH PASSWORD='changemealso'
CREATE USER TestB FOR LOGIN TestB
CREATE USER TestA FOR LOGIN TestA
GO
CREATE DATABASE Test3
GO
USE Test3
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, SomeColumn nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO someTable Values ('hello'), ('world')
CREATE USER TestB FOR LOGIN TestB
GRANT SELECT ON SomeTable To TestB

USE Test2
GO
CREATE VIEW SomeTable AS SELECT * FROM Test3.dbo.SomeTable
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SomeFunction()
RETURNS nvarchar(max) 
WITH EXECUTE AS 'TestB'
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT top 1 SomeColumn FROM SomeTable)
END
GO

GRANT EXEC ON dbo.SomeFunction to TestA

USE Test1
SELECT Test2.dbo.SomeFunction() -- this fails, even when logged in as sa. Interestingly though, it DOES return an empty result set - despite the error.

GO
use MASTER
DROP Database Test1
DROP Database Test2
DROP Database Test3

DROP Login TestA
DROP Login TestB
```

The error given is

```
The server principal "TestB" is not able to access the database "Test3" under the current security context.
```

Which somewhat baffles me as the user TestB has been explicitly given access to that database.

The idea is that the application will connect to Test1 as user TestA. It won't have direct access to the tables in Test3, but the functions on Test2 will allow access to a subset of that data.

Test2 and Test3 are separate databases for reasons unrelated to the security.

What have I missed that will allow this query to work?

```
SELECT Test2.dbo.SomeFunction()
```

UPDATE:
I think the problem stems from the `EXECUTE AS` clause attached to the function. It seems like this can only specify a user, not a login. And since a user is associated only with a single database, anything which uses `EXECUTE AS` cannot do anything with any other database.

This article suggests a possible workaround: http://blog.sqlxdetails.com/procedure-with-execute-as-login/ but it seems very convoluted and I'm concerned that there could be unintended side effects.

Any better workarounds?